# Open a song in Rhythmbox without importing it?

Tags: banshee, rhythmbox

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 so I have Rhythmbox installed by default. I don't mind to much, however I miss one thing from Banshee: "file system queue".

In Banshee, I had the option not to import a file opened via the file browser (or the dash). I can't find that option in Rhythmbox and I'd like to have it, since there are a lot of audio files which I don't want to have in my library.

Is there any plugin or something like that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge this is not a current function of Rythmbox.  If it plays a file, it will remember where it is so you can use it again.  Not sure why you'd *not* want this.

Unless you are using removable media or a network share that is not always present, then you may wind up with files in your catalog that cannot be played.

Why not email the team upstream and request this function?  Be clear why you think it would be beneficial to the community, because you are asking someone to spend time to code this function it is good if you have a compelling reason.

Comment: Well, I use some audio files that are not music and I just don't want them mixed with my real music. I don't want my library filled with "unknown artist" songs because the program wants to import every single file I open. I should be the one deciding if I want to import it or not.

Comment: Got ya.  It's a little extra work, but you could edit the _artist_, _album_, and _genre_ fields in the files so they slot into your overall catalog better.  I had similar issues with podcasts, and had to get into the habit of managing them as well.

Comment: You are right, but still, I don't want some songs to be there. For example, I sometimes record backing tracks for songs I compose. Those are just for work, nothing serious. So I don't want that song playing if I choose random mode. Anyway, if nobody claims you are wrong saying it's not posible I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: You could always continue using banshee.

Comment: @James I know, I just wanted to know if that was possible with Rhythmbox, since it's a bit faster. Or maybe I'll try Clementine, a lot of people say it's good.